# String comparison with German letter ß

Tags: c#, sql, linq, cultureinfo

I'm trying to get customers based on customer code:

```
var customer = GetAllCustomers()
               .FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerCode.ToLower().Trim() ==
                                    customerCode.ToLower().Trim());
```

In one case, `customerCode` is *"Andreas Graßl"* (I think it's a German name)

However, in the database (SQL Server 2008 R2) the data is saved as *"Andreas Grassl"* (ß became ss), and my query does not find a match.

Can someone please tell me whether this is a collation thing in the database or is this a culture thing in C#?
How can I fix it so that my query will return a match?

Comment: the problem is in the `saving process`. Your table should be designed with data type `nvarchar` which supports unicode.

Comment: @KingKing The custoemrCode column is nvarchar(500)

Comment: could i be that this replacement "ß" with "ss" is hardcoded somewhere? That at some time the table was varchar instead of nvarchar so the replacement was done by hand, and sometime later nvarchar was "discovered" but the code not fully migrated?

Comment: For the record: `ß` and `ss` are different characters. Although `ß` might sometimes be written as `ss` (mainly when dealing with ASCII, or, as Thorsten pointed out, when writing uppercase. In the days of unicode it shouldn't). So the query itself is technically correct. If you search for `Graßl` then `Grassl` will not be found.

Comment: Your real problem is that your key is a full name - names are unreliable, **not unique**, have many variations (Bob/Robert, typos, order, optional middle name), and change too often (marriage, divorce, whim). "CustomerCode" suggests a fixed ID string or number, not a full name.

Comment: If the name is "Graßl" your database should contain that and not "Grassl". That is a different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string str1="Andreas Graßl";
string str2="Andreas Grassl";
Console.WriteLine(string.Equals(str1,str2));  //False
Console.WriteLine(string.Equals(str1,str2,StringComparison.CurrentCulture));  //True
```

So I suggest you change your code with string.Equals()

Details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165449.aspx

Comment: Does this assume the current culture is German? According to the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx , this isn't very reliable, because you don't know what culture to use for each name.

Comment: @Kobi - I checked for both "nl-NL" and "en-US". Both return "True" for the CurrentCulture check (which I didn't expect)!

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to perform a "sounds like" search using [DIFFERENCE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE DIFFERENCE(Person.LastName, 'Graßl') >= x
```

Comment: If Kobi is right in his comment, this would hide the original problem and possibly lead to bigger issues later on.

Comment: Of course this hides the initial problem, but it answers his question about what he could to the get match.

Answer (score 0):

Please you run the script to re-updating CustomerCode by following Unicode format:

```
UPDATE Customer SET CustomerCode = N'Andreas Graßl' WHERE CustomerID = [YourCustomerID]
```

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

In German, `ß` and `ss` are used somewhat interchangeably. Is it possible the user input was `ss` during saving and later `ß` during lookup?

Comment: Ouch!! No, they are not! `ß` becomes `SS` only when you spell a word in capitals. `Straße` would become `STRASSE`, because there's no capital `ß`. Otherwise `ß` and `ss` are not interchangeable, because `ss` is only used after short vowels, while `ß` is used after long vowels and diphtones. Both do denote a "voiceless, sharp s". Please note that in Swiss German, there's no `ß` at all.

Comment: I used `somewhat` to indicate that absolute correctness was not the point. The point was whether it was possible that user input was inconsistent across two cases.

Comment: He's not that wrong as he wrote "somewhat interchangeable"...I know of some applications that implemented similar behaviour to workaround Unicode (or lack thereof) restrictions. Nevertheless a PITA... (BTW: Didn't know swiss german doesn't support it - thanks)